# Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: OHE

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

In categorical label encoding. I know that I need to use OneHotEncoder() because Feature names differs in test so cannot use pd_dummies. In train I have x rows and in test 1 row, after OHE the test row is shorter and I have no Idea how to compare it with train.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = df.apply(le.fit_transform)
X = dfle.values
ohe = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
X = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()


le = LabelEncoder()
testle = test.apply(le.fit_transform)
y = testle.values
two = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
y = two.fit_transform(y).toarray()


rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
rf.fit(X, y)

rf.predict([[ ? ]])
```

Output of X and y:

```
X:
[[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0.
  0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.
  1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
  0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1.
  0. 1.]]

y:
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you misunderstand what `X` and `y` mean. `X` represents your features, `y` your target(s). It's different from `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`. If `y` represents your test data, you should rename it to be clearer.

Here, it seems `y` is your test data:

> In train I have x rows and in test 1 row

You should use your first transformers (used for `X`) to transform (and only transform, not fit!) your data.

**What you should not do:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA', 'France'], 'language': ['EN', 'FR']})
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X_train = ohe.fit_transform(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA'], 'language': ['EN']})
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X_test = ohe.fit_transform(df2)

# X_train
# array([[0., 1., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0., 1.]])

# X_test
# array([[1., 1.]])  # shape differs from X_train
```

**What you should do:**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA', 'France'], 'language': ['EN', 'FR']})
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
X_train = ohe.fit_transform(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['USA'], 'language': ['EN']})
X_test = ohe.transform(df2)

# X_train
# array([[0., 1., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0., 1.]])

# X_test
# array([[0., 1., 1., 0.]])  # same shape as X_train
```